# DateTime.TryParseExact Parses date value but adds default time value (where there was none)

Tags: c#, date, datetime, c#-8.0

*edit*: since I've had so many comments regarding utilising TryParseExact with a single format instead of an array:

- I must test all of the formats within the array - the inputs can potentially be these formats, and my unit tests for these other formats actually work. I MUST use them all.
- I am aware that DateTime.TryParse would match the first and not iterate further. Hence I am using TryParseExact [as Microsoft shows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=net-5.0#System_DateTime_TryParseExact_System_ReadOnlySpan_System_Char__System_String___System_IFormatProvider_System_Globalization_DateTimeStyles_System_DateTime__). It should match *exactly*. BUT it doesn't work in this scenario.

**TLDR**: Given a string of the format `"dd/MM/yyyy"` with value `"29/11/2019"` DateTime.TryParseExact returns a match with the format `"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt"` and value `29/11/2019 12:00 AM`. Why?

#### Question: How can I ensure a string of the format `"dd/MM/yyyy"` returns as a match with the format `"dd/MM/yyyy"` instead of `"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt"` when using TryParseExact?

The long explanation of **Context**;

I have the following problem. I need to parse multiple date formats from strings to datetime values. They (input strings) can appear in the following formats:

`{ "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt", "dd/M/yyyy hh:mm tt", "dd/MM/yyyy H:mm", "dd/MM/yyyy H:mm", "dd/MM/yyyy H:m", "dd/MM/yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyy", "d-M-yyyy", "dddd, d MMMM yyyy"};`

To solve this, I wrote a string extension that parses a given input string and returns a bool success and a potential matching format.

```
  private static readonly string[] _DateFormats = new string[] { "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt", "dd/M/yyyy hh:mm tt", "dd/MM/yyyy H:mm", "dd/MM/yyyy H:mm", "dd/MM/yyyy H:m", "dd/MM/yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyy", "d-M-yyyy", "dddd, d MMMM yyyy"};

  public static bool StringToDateTime(this string dateTimeString, out DateTime dateTimeValue, out string matchingFormat)
  {
      matchingFormat = ""; // defaults
      dateTimeValue = new DateTime();
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dateTimeString)) return false;
      foreach (string format in DateFormats)
      {
          matchingFormat = format;
          if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateTimeString, DateFormats, AUSCulture, DateTimeStyle, out dateTimeValue)) return true;
      }
      return false;
  }
```

This returns the string input `"29/11/2019 successfully"` as the DateTime `29/11/2019 12:00 AM` with the matching format as `"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt"`, rather than the format matching the original input `29/11/2019`.

Given this issue, the only (duct-tape) solution I could think of is:

```
public static bool StringToDateTime(this string dateTimeString, out DateTime dateTimeValue, out string matchingFormat)
{
    matchingFormat = ""; // defaults
    dateTimeValue = new DateTime();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dateTimeString)) return false;
    foreach (string format in DateFormats)
    {
        matchingFormat = format;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateTimeString, DateFormats, AUSCulture, DateTimeStyle, out dateTimeValue))
        {
            // ensure the datetime format is consistent with the dateTimeString passed to us.
            if(dateTimeString.Length != matchingFormat.Length)
            {
                var _matchingFormat = DateFormats.First(d => d.Length == dateTimeString.Length);
                matchingFormat = string.IsNullOrEmpty(_matchingFormat) ? matchingFormat : _matchingFormat;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Which works, but obviously, this has further issues (begetting the formatting of input, etc.). So I'd rather not use this.

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean "returns a match with the format"? A `DateTime` always has a time component, which will be midnight by default. Also, `DateTime` does not have a format, it's a value representing a date and a time, converting it to a string involves a format. Simply looking at a `DateTime` value in the debugger will usually also show the time component. .NET 6 will get `TimeOnly` and `DateOnly` types, that won't have this, but `DateTime` **always** has both a date and a time component.

Comment: Please [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68174605/edit) so that it includes a proper [mcve], along with a detailed and specific description of what the code does, how that's different from what you expected, and what _exactly_ you need help with. Besides the fact that you seem to be confusing `TryParse()` and `TryParseExact()` (you mention both above), it seems likely that you have some unreasonable/incorrect expectation about how `DateTime` values work.

Comment: As others say, `DateTime` doesn't have a format. Internally, it's just [one 64-bit integer](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,132).

Comment: I'm referring to the time format returned from my function. I'll edit this to make it clearer again. I thought the TLDR saying that it returns with that value made it clear already.

Comment: @Karlsen I understand how both work and I most definitely am looking for an exact match with TryParseExact. I'm referring to TryParse and TryParse exact synonymously here, as either doesn't matter to my question: How can I ensure a string of the format "dd/MM/yyyy" returns as a match with the format "dd/MM/yyyy" instead of "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt" when using TryParseExact?

Comment: @theQuantumMechanic - Do you understand that `DateTime` values cannot match a format?

Comment: Why are you passing `DateFormats` in to the parse rather than _one_ of the formats?

Answer (score 5):

System.DateTime cannot exist without the time component, so it's no possible to parse a date to DateTime and not the time component. It will default to the start of day e.g. 12:00 AM, which is the same result as calling `dateTime.Date()`. This will allow you to compare two dates without considering the time of day.

If having or storing the time element really bothers you then you can either create your own `struct` to store the date or consider using something like [NodaTime](https://nodatime.org/) that provides a date only struct.

Also, Dotnet 6 will introduce DateOnly and TimeOnly structs to do exactly this. You can read more about it on the [MS devblogs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/date-time-and-time-zone-enhancements-in-net-6/).

Comment: I know that DateTime initialises with a default time value (hence the output). The problem is it matches the wrong format.

Answer (score 1):

**You are passing the whole array of formats, so it will match any of them.**

Since you are in a `foreach` over `DateFormats`, you only need to match against the current value.

So replace this line

```cs
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateTimeString, DateFormats, AUSCulture, DateTimeStyle, out dateTimeValue))
    return true;
```

with this

```cs
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateTimeString, format, AUSCulture, DateTimeStyle, out dateTimeValue))
    return true;
```

Comment: I want to match any format in the array, that's not the point.

Comment: You are in a `foreach` over `DateFormats` anyway, so it will match one of them eventually

Comment: Yes, the problem is it initially matches the first format and stops. Read the question I explained all of this.

Comment: Again, I read the question, and I'm trying to explain to you: you are passing **all of the formats** on every loop of the `foreach`, so it will always match any of the formats even on the first run. This is what you need to change. Have you actually tried the code I show?

Comment: I must attempt to match any of the formats in the array. This is a prerequisite. TryParseExact should be matching *exactly* - but it doesn't. This is my question. I don't need to try your code, as it doesn't actually solve my problem nor my question. How can I ensure it matches with the correct format *exactly*?

Comment: You are literally not reading a single word I said. I'll repeat myself again: **if you pass all the formats in one go, it will try to match *any* of them**, which is what you are doing inside the loop. Whereas if you pass only the loop variable `format` **only that one will match**. See this fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/9fE5B5